# Robotframework -: How check if element is enabled then click on it ,else move to next keyword

Tags: python, robotframework

To check if element is enabled then click on it ,else log some message without failing script-:

run keyword if     element should be visible    ${accounts_per_page} click on acc_per_page

...     ELSE IF    LOG     "Dropdown is not enabled"

I am getting below error -: Evaluating expression 'element should be visible' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider redesigning your test. If you absolutely have to you can use keyword **Run Keyword And Ignore Error** capture the return value and use it as a condition for your next test step with keyword **Run Keyword If**.

```
*** Test Cases ***   
Example                
    ${output}=    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Possible Failure
    Log    ${output}[0]
    Run Keyword If    '${output}[0]'=='FAIL'    Keyword With Next Step
```

If you use robot framework 5.0 you can use the newly added try/catch [functionality](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/rf-5.0b1.rst#try-except)
example taken from the resource.

```
*** Test Cases ***
First example
    TRY
        Some Keyword
    EXCEPT    Error message
        Error Handler Keyword
    END
    Keyword Outside
```